# How do I scrape between pattern and nth occurence of comma

Tags: php, regex, file, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a text file between a pattern, and the 12th comma of the string.
All I get is an empty page.

My expected result is:

```
WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE",200114,2020-01-14,001602,CBT ,00,001 , 476764, 146061, 107856, 162340, 136922
```

This is the code:

```
$scrape = scrape_between($scraped_page, 
                         'WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE', 
                         '/[.*^,]+,[.*^,]+,[.*^;]+,[.*^,]+,[.*^,]+/'
                         );
```

If I use some other pattern, like `fghi`, everything is fine and I get my result.

What is wrong?

The complete script is:

```
<?php
    function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
        $data = stristr($data, $start);
        $data = substr($data, strlen($start));
        $stop = stripos($data, $end);
        $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);
        return $data;
    }
    function curl($url) {
        $options = Array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
    $scraped_page = curl("https://www.cftc.gov/dea/newcot/deafut.txt");
    $scraped_wheat = scrape_between($scraped_page, 'WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE', '/(?:,[^,]+){11}/');

    echo ($scraped_wheat."<br>");
?>
```

Comment: *"I try to scrape a text file"* - An example of it would probably help.

Comment: Of course I can provide the text:
‘’’
"WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE",200114,2020-01-14,001602,CBT ,00,001 ,  476764,  146061,  107856,  162340,  136922,  159403,  445323,  429599,   31441,   47165,  292143,  133612,  127892,   52228,   85292,   84664,  271132,  264784,   21011,   27359,  184621,   86118,   53633,   36443,   51630,   74739,  174191,  164815,   10430,   19806,   42091,   10308,    6429,   26096,    3326,    7100,   39730,   39625,    ..."
‘’’

Comment: `[.*^,]+` means 1 or more any character `.` or `*` or `^` or `,`. I'm pretty sure that is not what you want.

Comment: If it's a CSV file, wouldn't it be easier to read it into a comma separated array and then take the parts you are interested in from the result.

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: Oh I thought `[.*^,]+` means any character except the comma. Am I wrong?

Comment: The result should be: `WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE",200114,2020-01-14,001602,CBT ,00,001 , 476764, 146061, 107856, 162340, 136922`

Comment: What you want is `[^,]+` and the regex `(?:,[^,]+){11}`

Comment: I am sorry. I tried it like `'/(?:,[^,]+){11}/'` and like `'(?:,[^,]+){11}'` both did't work. No result.

Comment: I cannot find the method `scrape_between` in PHP's manual. Can you share a full working example of your code, containing all needed inputs and the expected outputs for at least one basic case?

Comment: I just added the complete script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use regex for this. Try something along these lines and see if it works:

```
$pieces = explode('"
"', $scraped_page);
$items = explode(",",$pieces[0]);
$tmp = 0;
foreach ($items as $value) if ($tmp++ < 12) {
    echo ($value.",");
}
```

The output I get is:

> "WHEAT-SRW - CHICAGO BOARD OF TRADE",200114,2020-01-14,001602,CBT ,00,001 ,  476764,  146061,  107856,  162340,  136922,